# What is the difference between a string and a collation?

Tags: logic, terminology

Could someone please explain the difference between a string and a collation in mathematical logic?

Comment: You can see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867031/what-are-the-differences-between-a-collation-and-a-rule-of-formation).